# curl_exec() prints the returned JSON data, won't put it into a variable

Tags: php, curl

There are many such questions on Stack Overflow & elsewhere, but they all seem to be for earlier versions of PHP as their answers refer to `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, `open_basedir` and `allow_url_include`.

I am using PHP 5.4.17. Here’s my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

if ($curl === False)
{
  die('Fatal error initiating CURL');
}

curl_setopt_array($curl, 
   array(CURLOPT_HTTPGET => True,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => True,
         CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => True,
          CURLOPT_URL => $gatewayURL . $parameters 
         ));

$rawJasonData = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl); 

if ($rawJasonData === False)
```

The code seems to be OK—although I will admit that this is my first time using CURL—because the returned JSON data is echoed.

I want to capture it in a variable, how do I do that (without resorting to output buffering)?

---

[Update] I am **certain** that I don't `var_dump()` or `echo` the result myself. Neither 1 instead of True, nor uppercase TRUE make any difference.

I am developing locally, but using an entry in the Windows HOST file in my URL, not localhost.

Comment: Is this your whole code?  Are you sure you are not echoing it yourself anywhere?

Comment: What does `var_dump($rawJasonData)` show?  Is it your JSON data, or is it `TRUE` (or `FALSE`)?

Comment: What happens if you remove CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION?

Comment: +1 It shows nothing at all. So, it seems to be an empty string, rather than false. It is as if the curl_exec(), by echoing the result, is consuming it.

Comment: +1 but emoving CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION makes no difference

Comment: And what happens if you manually go to the URL? echo out $gatewayURL . $parameters and go to the URL in your browser. Are you getting anything there?

Comment: @Mawg: Does `var_dump($rawJasonData)` actually not print anything, or do you see `string(0) ""`?

Comment: As an aside, you can use file_get_contents($gatewayURL . $parameters) to get the data as well :)

Comment: Going direct to the URL prints my JSON. And var_dump shows an empty string. I sandwich it between echoed brackets & see them, with nothing between.

Comment: @Mawg: Huh?  So, you're not seeing `string(0) ""` or `string(7) "[1,2,3]"` or something similar?  Check the source of the page.  `var_dump()` will ***always*** echo *something*.  Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to your script to see if there are any errors/warnings.

Comment: I thought that file_get_contents is problematic if you don't control PHP.ini - I want this to be widely usable, even on cheap or free hosting. It doesn't have to be CURL, just a way to get JSON with as few restrictions as possible.

Comment: I personally use file_get_contents on various shared hosts without issue.

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents(0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\Dropbox\programs\xampp\htdocs\Gateway.php on line 576`  BUT ... 
F:\Dropbox\programs\xampp\htdocs>dir Gateway.php
 Volume in drive F is Synched data
 Volume Serial Number is 0CFC-919D

 Directory of F:\Dropbox\programs\xampp\htdocs

30/05/2014  03:01 AM            31,680 Gateway.php
               1 File(s)         31,680 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   6,187,225,088 bytes free

Comment: @Mawg: Are you trying to use `F:\Dropbox\programs\xampp\htdocs\Gateway.php` as your URL in `file_get_contents`?  If you want the PHP to execute, then you'll need to access it via an `http://` URL.  Such as `http://localhost/Gateway.php`.

Comment: Rocket, nope. I substituted another variable, the URL, and yes, I saw string[92] ... but for $rawJasonData it's just nothing at all (!)

Comment: Nope. ` $rawJasonData = file_get_contents($gatewayURL + $parameters);`  and it's definitely a `http://`

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused. What output does file_get_contents produce if you use the exact same URL?

Comment: I'm confused too.  It's impossible for `var_dump` to echo nothing unless error reporting is off.

Comment: Ian, See above, starting "warning"

Comment: So it's producing 'file_get_contents(0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\Dropbox\programs\xampp\htdocs\Gateway.php' when you try to file_get_contents("http://www.someurl.com/gateway.php?parameters=1")?

Comment: Post the *exact* url that you're trying to access via file_get_contents.

Comment: Weird. If I var_dump($rawJasonData) before the curl_init, I see NULL, which is what we expect, but afterwards, I don't see anything at all. AND, if I place another variable in the var_dump then I see what we expect. The main problem is why the JSON is received successfully, but is echoed & stored in a variable.

Comment: `   echo 'Attempt to open <a href="' . $gatewayURL . $parameters . '">' .  $gatewayURL . $parameters  . '</a>';
   $rawJasonData = file_get_contents($gatewayURL + $parameters);  die();`   gives `Attempt to open http://isatdatapro.skywave.com/GLGW/GWServices_v1/RestMessages.svc/get_return_messages.json/?<some params>  Warning: file_get_contents(0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\Dropbox\programs\xampp\htdocs\Gateway.php on line 576`

Comment: @Mawg: You might actually be experiencing the issues that you were talking about earlier.  You might need to check `allow_url_fopen` in your php.ini.

Comment: I was hoping that you were correct & I could just say D'oh! and move on. But allow_url_fopen  is On

Comment: I can't believe it took me this long to notice........ `file_get_contents($gatewayURL.$parameters);`  You use `.` to concat strings, not `+`.  The error had it right there.  You were trying to run `file_get_contents(0)`.

Comment: AAAAAAAARGH!!   I have been moving between C, PHP & JS for weeks now & this isn't the first time that this has happened!!  Please post that as answer, while everyone gathers round & shouts obscenities at me.  (sorry, it's 3:30 am here & I am pulling an all-nighter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why cURL isn't working for you, but since you are just making a simple GET request, why not just do:

```
$rawJasonData = file_get_contents($gatewayURL.$parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much!!  Bt, is there a "bst practise", such as `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php`? Sounds like it's `file_get_contents`, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: @Mawg: What do you mean by "best practice"?  Whatever works you is fine.  That `http_get` function isn't a built-in function, so I wouldn't suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

Likely a non issue, but:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, 
                   array(CURLOPT_HTTPGET => 1,
                         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                         CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                         CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
                         CURLOPT_URL => $gatewayURL . $parameters));
```

In previous versions of PHP, I encountered significant issues with using True when setting curl options. Give 1 a shot and see what happens. This worked for me, but it could have been due to the environment I was working in. Just wanting to mention this in case you have some weird environment (like I had) that caused the most odd problems.

As for personal preference, I prefer using the following method to set options:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
```

As for your question -- I'd remove CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION as that will follow redirects and you shouldn't have any in your case.

I suspect that CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is the issue here.

Comment: The docs say that `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` should be a boolean, not an int.  It may cast the int to a boolean, though.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: I don't know what URL he's accessing, maybe he *does* need `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.  I can't see how that would be the cause of any issues.

Comment: If the header contains a redirect, the data will be empty (i.e., it will not contain any JSON.)

Comment: As I say, I am new to CURL. I added that CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION when looking at someone else's code. Removing it makes no difference. I am accessing my own server & there will be no redirection, so that is a red herring. Sorry about that (+ all round)

Answer (score 0):

The big issue I am seeing with your code is the use of the first uppercase in `True` and `False` when it should be `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Here is my refactored version of your code that should work:

```
$curl = curl_init();

if (!$curl) {
  die('Fatal error initiating CURL');
}

$curl_options = array();
$curl_options['CURLOPT_HTTPGET'] = TRUE;
$curl_options['CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER'] = TRUE;
$curl_options['CURLOPT_HTTPGET'] = TRUE;
$curl_options['CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER'] = array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json');
$curl_options['CURLOPT_URL'] = $gatewayURL . $parameters;

curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_options);

$rawJasonData = curl_exec($curl); 

curl_close($curl); 

if (!$rawJasonData)
```

I added `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` as `TRUE` to force `GET` behavior from curl as well as JSON related headers in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Past all of that you have checks that were set as `=== False` which are a bit excessive.  Simply setting a `if (!$curl) {` and an `if (!$rawJasonData)` would work as expected.

If that still somehow does not work, change the `TRUE` values to a `1` like this:

```
$curl_options = array();
$curl_options['CURLOPT_HTTPGET'] = 1;
$curl_options['CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER'] = 1;
$curl_options['CURLOPT_HTTPGET'] = 1;
```

Comment: The docs say that you should set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to a boolean, not an int.  I assume PHP will cast it as one.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php